# Lightest possible adapter for Dell XPS with optional power bank features

Tags: laptop, adapter, power-bank

I have a Dell XPS 15 laptop, and am looking for a power adapter with specific requirements. Here's what I'm after:

- **Must have**

  - Works on XPS 15 9550 (ir-6700HQ with 1080p screen)
  - Works with EU (Dutch) Type F power sockets
  - Can *at least* support my laptop in "Balanced" power mode doing moderate development work (typically CPU usage < 50%, no big GPU usage) while not *draining* battery
  - Can charge my laptop about from 10% to 80% when idling with screen off

In short, it should allow me to at least continue working while on power, and start charging the battery if I leave my PC in idle mode.

To further specify, I've measured how much power my laptop currently draws. It wants about 30 Watt when CPU usage is low to idling, and draws about 65 Watt at peak moments (e.g. when I'm running a few builds). Over an 8 hour day, I measured 0.20 kWh, which means about 26 Watt. These measurements were taken using a 130 Watt adapter.

Additionally:

- **Should have**

  - Offer Powerbank features for charging a smartphone
  - As light as possible (while still offering enough power per musthaves, above)
- **Nice to have**

  - Official Dell branded hardware
  - Powerbank supports QuickCharge through usb-c

Price is not too important: although I don't need a gold-plated or autographed device, I'm happy to pay a premium to get all functionalities in.

I have tried and returned the PH45W17-CA (12800 mAh usb-c powerbank with 45W adapter), as it was incompatible with my model.

For reference, charging over USB-C will *not* work on the 9550 with *some* adapters (incl the above, as well as one I borrowed from a colleague's Thinkpad), but it *will* work with others (e.g. some Apple chargers I borrowed in the past, as well as my [WD15 Dock](https://www.dell.com/support/article/nl/nl/nlbsdt1/sln304627/dell-dock-wd15-usb-type-c-information-compatibility-and-specifications?lang=en)).

Comment: Any idea what wattage (:-)) you're pulling under any load? Any access to a Kill A Watt (:-)) P4460? Or at least what is the output wattage on your original charger? I don't know what GPU you have, but I'd easily guess your machine needs over 100W at load

Comment: Hmm, I don't know how much power I'm using, and not sure if I have or know of software to measure this. Might need to borrow a measuring _device_ to check this. I know my current 130 watt "travel" adapter is overkill for mentioned CPU loads. GPU doesn't need to do too much except power extra monitors, I typically have only developer tools running.

Comment: It's impossible to fully answer without knowing the power draw for the settings that allow you to work comfortably. Also most likely what you're looking for (as per must haves #1-3 and should have #1) doesn't and won't exist. The best I could do is give a few minimalistish charger + battery bank ideas that could work? I'd need a better idea of your display requirements to proceed

Comment: I've measured usage and updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

So there's still the unknown of why a Dell 45W USB-C charger did not work on a Dell machine. Given your measured power draw, it might be that your machine doesn't support that charger without some firmware update or just doesn't support charging via USB-C. Maybe try some other USB-C laptop chargers (45W+) you can get a hold to see if they work. For this section I'll assume your machine can't charge via USB-C.

So the only closest to spec item I can come up with is the soon to be released **Omnicharge Omni 20+** with a Dell barrel connector. The connector may be included or you may need to order it, I'm reasonably *assuming* that their Dell connector is compatible with your machine. It's much neater than using the AC outlet. Here's their [site](https://www.omnicharge.co/). As long as your power draw is under 100W using the Omni 20+, must haves 1, 3 and 4 should be easily met. Must have 2 is more so within your control, as you can charge/power the unit through either the barrel connector or USB-C connected to a Euro power socket. It's also a power bank with 60W USB-C output and it's probably as light as it's going to be for your spec, if/until something else comes along (highly unlikely from Dell).

---

If it turns out that your machine can be charged via USB-C the options expand: Omni 20 USB-C, Omni 13+, [HyperJuice](https://www.hypershop.com/products/hyperjuice-130w-27000mah-most-powerful-usb-c-battery-pack?variant=19716546527294), [Batpower](https://batpower.com/), a few others.

Just a suggestion: A [75W Dual Type-C PD Travel Charger](https://satechi.net/collections/usb-type-c/products/75w-dual-type-c-pd-travel-charger), could power a laptop with the 60W port, a phone/power bank with the 18W port and other devices tucked away with the remaining ports. Pretty clean and small.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Based on your questions, I did find [this dell.com forum post](https://www.dell.com/support/article/nl/nl/nlbsdt1/sln304627/dell-dock-wd15-usb-type-c-information-compatibility-and-specifications?lang=en) suggesting my device supports USB-C charging, _only_ if it's "PD and at least 60W". It seems all your suggestions support that 

Comment: Ah yeah that's why I was concerned about the wattage, you've a HQ processor not a U or other low voltage processor that can take advantage of ~<45W USB-C chargers. PD over USB-C/TB3 theoretically maxes at 100W but it's pretty hard to find chargers capable of over 60W 